# Database driven form laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a question in regards to Designing a Database Driven Form.
So my high-level DB Design is like. I will also attach some mock data. Json value will be populated in case of a checkbox

```
Table Name : Form Element
Columns:    fieldName   fieldLabel,                  jsonValues, type 
            UserName    Name        ,                 NULL  ,     Text
            Student     Are You a Student      ,      NULL    ,   Radio
```

So using this table i want to create a dynamic form which contains one text and a radio button. I would like to abstract the implementation of text and radio as maybe a function like `displayText` and `displayRadio`. and the HTML is defined in those functions.

How can this be effectively implemented using Blade in laravel 4.2. Assuming my controller returns all the data to the vie

Comment: It may sound discouraging, I wish you can consider switching your direction, choose front end library/framework like React.js or Angular instead which are designed for this purpose.

Comment: Im open to that suggestion, just want to actually check if there is a feasible way of doing it using Laravel and Bootstrap. Need some ideas. Thats about it